# Растянуть Яндекс карты на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

Помогите растянуть карты iframe внутри выдвигающегося меню

CSS

```
.top-panel {
background: #39464e;
position: fixed;
top: -400px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
padding: 0;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
transition: top 500ms cubic-bezier(0.17,0.04,0.03,0.94);

}

iframe{height: 400px;width: 100%;}
```

HTML

```
<input class="open" id="top-box" type="checkbox" hidden>
   <label class="btn" for="top-box"></label>
    <div class="top-panel">

        <div class="mapmap">
           <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CBBMnWq02D"  frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
  var isChecked = $('.open').prop('checked');
  if(!isChecked) {
    $('.top-panel').animate({ 
      'top': '0'
    },1000);
    $('.btn').text('Закрыть карту');
  } else {
    $('.top-panel').animate({ 
      'top': '-100%'
    },1000);
    $('.btn').text('Открыть карту');
  }
});
```

```css
.top-panel {
  background: #39464e;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  transition: top 500ms cubic-bezier(.17,.04,.03,.94);
}

.mapmap, .mapmap iframe{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
              0 2px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="open" id="top-box" type="checkbox" hidden>
<label class="btn" for="top-box">Открыть карту</label>

<div class="top-panel">

  <div class="mapmap">
    <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CBBMnWq02D" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

  </div>
</div>
```